# Lipschitz norm on a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

The following is a question from my homework assignment:

A function $f : [1, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ is said to be a Lipschitz function if there is a constant $L$ such that
$$|f(s) − f(t)| \leq L|s − t|$$ for all $s, t ∈ [−1, 1]$.

For such a function we define $Lip(f)$ to be the smallest constant $L$ such that the above inequality holds. Let $Z$ be the real vector space consisting of all Lipschitz functions on $[−1, 1]$ and $X$ be the subspace of $Z$ consisting of those $f$ for which $f(0) = 0$.

$(i)$ Show that setting $||f||_{Lip} = Lip(f)$ defines a norm on $X$. Does the same formula define a norm on $Z$?

**My attempt** We basically have to prove the $3$ axioms which are needed for a norm.

$(N0)$ The norm is obviously finite by definition;

$(N1)$ It's also non-negative

$(N2)$ Scaling is also obvious

$(N3)$ The triangle inequality follows from summing up the $2$ definitions of Lipschitz continuity and applying the triangle inequality for the modulus.

My problem is that I've never used that fact that $f(0)=0$ and the norm would seem to be applicable to $Z$, too. However I read a bit about the Lipschitz norm in general and it always includes $|f(0)|$ as a term so this makes me question the validity of my solution.

Any advice is appreciated.

**Edit1** I've also checked $||f||_{Lip}=0 \implies f=0$

**Edit2** Thanks to the kind person in the comments section I realised where the mistake was

Comment: Part of the definition of a norm is that $\|g\| = 0 \iff g = 0$. You seem to have missed this part.

Comment: Ok, then a followup to your edit: Your check must be incorrect, because it is not true for $Z$. What is the Lipschitz constant of any constant function?

Comment: Oh, you're right, I've concluded that $f(x)$ is constant and have then used $f(0)=0 $ but have not written anything. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome.